# Flutter google calendar asks for Oauth consent every time

Tags: flutter, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar API to fetch the events of a user in flutter.

```
    var _clientID = new ClientId(
    "Client ID",
    "");
const _scopes = const [cal.CalendarApi.CalendarScope];
await clientViaUserConsent(_clientID, _scopes, prompt)
    .then((AuthClient client) async {

  CalendarService.calendar = cal.CalendarApi(client);
});
List<Event> futureevent = await calendarService.getevents();
futureevent.forEach((element) {
  print(element.summary);
});

return futureevent;
```

The problem is this is redirecting me to Oauth consent screen every time. Is there any way to store the authclient ID or any other way to make this get oauth consent screen only once when user opens it for first time.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to enable `offline access`

This means that once the user grants the access once - your app can store the users refresh token and generate a new access token when necessary - in the background, without the user needing to give a new consent each time.

For more details I recommend you to read

[Refreshing an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will check that and revert back